# XSLT - List position issue

Tags: xml, xslt

My Input xml contain multiple list as shown below.

```
<listing>
    <item><p>abcd</p></item></listing>        
<listing>
    <item><p>abcd</p></item></listing>        
<listing>
    <item><p>abcd</p></item></listing>        
<listing>
    <item><p>abcd</p></item></listing>
```

Output should be,

```
<listing id="p01" aid:pstyle="First" pagebreak="no">
<item><p>abcd</p>
</item>
</listing>        
<listing id="p02" aid:pstyle="Middle" pagebreak="no">
<item><p>abcd</p>
</item></listing>
<listing id="p03" aid:pstyle="Middle" pagebreak="no">
<item><p>abcd</p>
</item>
</listing>        
<listing id="p04" aid:pstyle="last" pagebreak="no">
<item><p>abcd</p>
</item></listing>
```

My xslt is like as,

```
<xsl:template match="listing">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:text>p</xsl:text>
            <xsl:number format="00" level="any"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="aid:pstyle">
<xsl:text>First</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:if test="not(attribute::pagebreak)">
            <xsl:attribute name="pagebreak">no</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>            
        <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:text>p</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:number format="00" level="any"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="aid:pstyle">
                    <xsl:text>last</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:if test="not(attribute::pagebreak)">
                    <xsl:attribute name="pagebreak">no</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>                
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="parent::listing">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:text>p</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:number format="00" level="any"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="aid:pstyle">
                    <xsl:text>Level</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::listing)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:if test="not(attribute::pagebreak)">
                    <xsl:attribute name="pagebreak">no</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>                
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>                
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:text>p</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:number format="00" level="any"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="aid:pstyle">
                            <xsl:text>Middle</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:if test="not(attribute::pagebreak)">
                        <xsl:attribute name="pagebreak">no</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>        
</xsl:template>
```

While using above xslt, we are not getting "pstyle" attribute value change as "First" for position first. We are getting incorrect output as,

```
<listing id="p01" aid:pstyle="Middle" pagebreak="no">
<item><p>abcd</p>
</item>
</listing>
<listing id="p02" aid:pstyle="Middle" pagebreak="no">
<item><p>abcd</p>
</item>
</listing>        
<listing id="p03" aid:pstyle="Middle" pagebreak="no">
<item><p>abcd</p>
</item>
</listing>        
<listing id="p04" aid:pstyle="last" pagebreak="no">
<item><p>abcd</p>
</item></listing>
```

Could you please guide us, why this xslt is not giving correct value for position 1.

Comment: Please add a tag for the XSLT version that you are using. This will help in providing appropriate solution.

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: There are 4 `<listing>` elements in the input XML whereas the output has 3 probably starting from the 2nd element. Is that what is required (ignore the 1st element)? Also where is the logic to populate the value of attribute `inddid` in the XSLT?

Comment: @Ankit, I have updated the Input and output which i required. Sorry for the incorrect content.

Comment: I do not see any issue with the XSLT. Using the input XML and XSLT shared by you, the desired output is achieved. Please check here [xsltransform.net/naZXpY3](http://xsltransform.net/naZXpY3). You need to optimize the XSLT as it has lot of redundant code.

Comment: The issue may not be in the template matching "listing" but in the template that matches the parent of "listing". Is this parent template explicitly doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="listing" />` or just `<xsl:apply-templates />`. Showing a complete XSLT sample that demonstrates the problem would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try count function for that:

```
<xsl:template match="listing">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:text>p</xsl:text>
                <xsl:number format="00" level="any"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="aid:pstyle">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(preceding::listing)=0">
                        <xsl:text>First</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>            
                    <xsl:when test="count(following::listing)=0">
                        <xsl:text>last</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="parent::listing">
                        <xsl:text>Level</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::listing)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>                
                        <xsl:text>Middle</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="not(attribute::pagebreak)">
                <xsl:attribute name="pagebreak">no</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `position()` at the top level of an xsl:template rule is the position of the matching node in the list of nodes selected by xsl:apply-templates. You haven't shown us the call on xsl:apply-templates, which is crucial in this case. If you aren't stripping whitespace text nodes, and if the `xsl:apply-templates` selects all child nodes, then the whitespace text nodes are going to be included in the `position()` count, which means that the first listing element is not the first node. Use `<xsl:apply-templates select="listing"/>` and the problem will then disappear.